# lose pointer adress when Timer_callback is called ON STM32

Tags: c, timer, callback, stm32

I am working with a STM32F103 and I have some trouble when the timer_callback is called. I'm working on CANopen_node and I made some of changes on the stack because I'm working with the HAL.  When I initialise the CAN module using structures with a function like `CO_init (CAN_HandleTypeDef CANbaseAddress,uint8_t nodeId, uint16_t bitRate)`, everything goes right. But when I enable and start the Timer interrupt I lose all what I have on CAN module init.

Does anyone know why I lose values of my CAN module when a callback is performed;
code:

```
COO is static variable.
 in COO variable 

    typedef struct{
        CO_CANmodule_t     *CANmodule[1];   /**< CAN module objects */
        CO_SDO_t           *SDO[CO_NO_SDO_SERVER]; /**< SDO object */
        CO_EM_t            *em;             /**< Emergency report object */
        CO_EMpr_t          *emPr;           /**< Emergency process object */
        CO_NMT_t           *NMT;            /**< NMT object */
        CO_SYNC_t          *SYNC;           /**< SYNC object */
        CO_RPDO_t          *RPDO[CO_NO_RPDO];/**< RPDO objects */
        CO_TPDO_t          *TPDO[CO_NO_TPDO];/**< TPDO objects */
        CO_HBconsumer_t    *HBcons;         /**<  Heartbeat consumer object*/
    #if CO_NO_SDO_CLIENT == 1
        CO_SDOclient_t     *SDOclient;      /**< SDO client object */
    #endif
    #if CO_NO_TRACE > 0
        CO_trace_t         *trace[CO_NO_TRACE]; /**< Trace object for monitoring variables */
    #endif
    }CO_t;
    CO_t *CO = NULL;
```

good init befor callback
[image: good init befor callback]

after callback
[image: after callback]

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MCU has only 20 kBytes of RAM, like the STM32F103C8 "Blue Pill", then the value of `CANbaseAddress`, `0x20004FC0` before the call, is suspiciously close to the end of RAM at `0x20005000`.

It is most certainly declared as a local variable in a function that has already finished, the memory allocated for this structure (on the stack) is freed up, and used for something else.

Declare the structure as **`static`** when you need its value later through a pointer.

Comment: @LENTMAISUR Then it's a local copy of a static struct. Nobody can guess it if you don't show the relevant code.

Comment: if I did not show the corresponding code it's because it would take whole pages.

Comment: i did declared the structure typedef struct{..}CO_t then i declared that like : extern CO_t *CO; all this in .h then i declared in .c  static CO_t COO;
    CO_t * CO = NULL;

Comment: I'm speaking of the **`CANbaseAddress`** field, whose value is an address of a local variable. You have a variable of type `CAN_HandleTypeDef` somewhere declared inside a function without `static`.

Comment: @LENTMAISUR the site can handle several pages of code quite well. Users might be able to guess some missing information, or they might not bother.

Comment: in my code  CANbaseAddress is a pointer to CAN_HandleTypeDef and it's a field of CO_CANmodule_t struct, and CO_CANmodule_t i did declared it like  "static CO_CANmodule_t       COO_CANmodule;"

Comment: @LENTMAISUR Once again, for the third and last time, read it carefully: `CANbaseAddress` **POINTS TO a variable which is not `static`**, but declared as a local variable in a function. If you still don't get it, read it again, then my answer and comments again and again. Every word of them. Or consider posting *relevant* code.